# How to access PartialView model in Parent View - ASP.NET Core MVC 2?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0. I have parent view, lets say `TakeOrders` and it has a  partial-view `Order Item` (which comes from external source and is a expensive operation).
I am rendering this partial view on parent view's button click , which makes a jQuery Ajax request to controller and controller return

```
return PartialView("OrderItems", OrderItemsVM);
```

And I inject this html response from my jQuery POST success method to my Div.

Now my problem is I want to have access to this `OrderItemsVM` in my parent view (`TakeOrders`). Because when user is done , then I want to send one Ajax POST request to server containing Parent View data + Child View data.

Could you please guide me on how to share child partialview data to parent view ?

Can I load `OrderItemsVM` (as `JSON` object) from Ajax POST and then render partial view in Razor ? but for this I have to convert this `JSON` object to .Net object to be able to do this

```
@{ @Html.Partial("OrderItems", JsonOrderItemsVM); }
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The partial view result you get from first ajax call, you can add that to DOM, probably inside a form in the DOM. As long as the names of the inputs matches with your view model property hierarchy (Which you use in your http post action method as parameter), model binding will work.

Comment: I don't have problem with model binding. My problem is I want to access PartialView model in my main parent view.

Comment: Response of `return PartialView` is html and it doesn't include `model` as `OrderItemsVM` but you can `serialize` form data to your object and use it.

Comment: @Ali how can I do this ? Can you give code example ? And is it possible that I could convert my JSON object to .NET object and use it in Razor code block ?